# iPhone Provisioning "Preparing to add to portal"

Tags: macbook, iphone, xcode

After connecting my iPhone to a new Mac, then trying to right click auto provision in Organizer, I get "preparing to add to portal" - ongoing for many minutes now. Any idea what's going on?